# Could not find declaration file for module 'velocity-animate'

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I am trying to use the `velocity-animate` Module in my Vue Project.

When i hover over the import statement in the module I get the following warning:

*Could not find a declaration file for module 'velocity-animate'. '/path/to/node_modules/velocity-animate/velocity.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/velocity-animate` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'velocity-animate';`*

I've already tried `npm i --save-dev @types/velocity-animate` but it does not work.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs help about this topic ...

Just simply make a file at the project root named `global.d.ts` and list your `declare module 'x'` statements all in that one file.

In your case add `declare module 'velocity-animate'`

For more information:
[follow this link](https://www.detroitlabs.com/blog/2018/02/28/adding-custom-type-definitions-to-a-third-party-library/)